# Determine all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $xf(y)+yf(x)=(x+y)f(x^2+y^2)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ (contest question)

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

The question below is from the 2002 Canada National Olympiad. I have found one family of functions but need help in finding (or proving the non-existence) of others. Suggestions on how to improve the solution method (especially rigour of arguments) would also be appreciated.

> Let $\mathbb{N} = {0,1,2,\dots}$. Determine all functions $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that
>
> $xf(y) + yf(x) = (x + y)f(x^2 + y^2) \tag{1}$
>
> for all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

Expressing $f$ as a power series:

$f(t) = a_0 + \displaystyle{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k x^k}} \tag{2}$

Assuming the power series is convergent, the general coefficient, $a_n$, is the same on both sides of equation (1). [I am not sure of this step].

So for $a_0$

$x(a_0) + y(a_0)=(x+y)(a_0)$

which is satisfied for all values of $a_0$. Hence $\boxed{f(t)=a_0,\:a_0\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a solution.

For any $n > 0$, we have

$\begin{align}
x a_n y^n + y a_n x^n &= (x+y)a_n(x^2+y^2)^n \iff \\ 
a_n(xy^n+yx^n) &= a_n(x+y)(x^2+y^2)^n
\end{align}$

and if this is true for fixed $n>0$ and all $x,y\ge0$ then $a_n=0$. So I am unable to find any other functions.

Comment: See this: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h77782p445898

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set $g(x):=f(x)-f(1)$, the we know that $f(x)=f(2x^{2})$ and so the function $g$ (and $f$) can not be a polynomial), because $g$ has infinitely roots. Now we show that the function $g$ must be zero. Assume that there is $x_{0}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g(x_{0})\neq 0$, since $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable set, let $x_{0}$ be an element s.t., $g(x_{0})$ has minimum value, but the following relation show that it's impossible and so $g\equiv 0$ i.e., $f(x)=f(1)$ on $\mathbb{N}$. 
If $f(1)<f(x_{0})$, then 
$$f(1)<f(1+x_{0}^{2})<f(x_{0}),$$
if $f(x_{0})<f(1)$, then
$$f(x_{0})<f(x_{0}^{2}+1)<f(1).$$
You can obtain the above relations with $f(x^{2}+y^{2})=\dfrac{xf(y)+yf(x)}{x+y}$.

Comment: Did you mean "$g(x_0)$ has minimum non-zero _absolute_ value"?

Comment: Thanks. That's an elegant proof.

Comment: @Marconius yes, the $g(x_{0})$ has minimum absolute value property, you're welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Set $y=0$. This gives us
$$xf(0)=xf(x^2)$$
for all $x$, and so $f(x^2)=f(0)$ for all $x$.

Now take $x=3n^2$ and $y=4n^2$ for some $n$. We get that
$$3n^2 f(4n^2) + 4n^2 f(3n^2) = 7n^2 f(25n^4)$$
Since $f(4n^2)=f(25n^4)=f(0)$, we get
$$4n^2 f(3n^2) = 4n^2 f(0)$$
and so $f(3n^2)=f(0)$ for all $n$.

Next, let $x=12n^2$ and $y=5n^2$ for some $n$. Then
$$12n^2 f(5n^2) + 5n^2 f(12n^2) = 17n^2 f(169n^4)$$
Again, since $f(12n^2)=f(169n^4)=f(0)$, we get that
$$12n^2 f(5n^2) = 12n^2 f(0)$$
and so $f(5n^2)=f(0)$ for all $n$.

Now let $x=2n^2$ and $y=n^2$ for some $n$. We get that
$$2n^2 f(n^2) + n^2 f(2n^2) = 3n^2 f(5n^2)$$
and since $f(n^2)=f(5n^2)=f(0)$, we get that
$$n^2 f(2n^2) = n^2 f(0)$$
giving us that $f(2n^2)=f(0)$ for all $n$.

Finally, let $x=y$. This gives us
$$2xf(x) = 2xf(2x^2)=2xf(0)$$
for all $x$, and so $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x$.

Thus the only functions satisfying the equation are constant functions, and we can check that any constant function does indeed satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $\mathbb{N} = {0,1,2,\dots}$. Determine all functions $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that
>
> $xf(y) + yf(x) = (x + y)f(x^2 + y^2) \tag{OP}$
>
> for all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $k=x=y$, then we get
$$
k f(k) + k f(k) = (k+k) f( k^2 + k^2)
f(x) = f(2x^2)
$$

which implies

> $$
> f(k) = f( 2 k^2 ) \tag{1}
> $$

Let $P^n_\mathbb{N}(k)$ be a polynomial $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, where $k^n$ is the highest power.

When we try
$$
f(k) = P^n_\mathbb{N}(k)
$$

then we obtain
$$
f(k^2) = P^n_\mathbb{N}(k^2) = P^{2n}_\mathbb{N}(k).
$$

Whence, due to (1) we get

> $$
> P^n_\mathbb{N}(k) = P^{2n}_\mathbb{N}(k) \Longrightarrow n = 2n
> \Longrightarrow n = 0.
> $$

So the conclusion is that $f(k)$ is just a constant.
Thus

> $$
> f(k) = c \in \mathbb{N}.
> $$

Comment: This argument shows that $f$ cannot be a polynomial. How would it follow that $f$ cannot be some other pathological function?

Comment: Good point. I need to think about this.

Comment: From the relation $f(x^{2})=f(0)$ or $f(x)=f(2 x^{2})$ immediately implies that the function $f$ can not be a polynomial. Since any polynomial has only finitely roots.