# Dimension of subspace defined by $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2 \Rightarrow f(a)+f(b)=f(c)+f(d)$

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic, functional-equations

Let $V={\mathbb Q}^{\mathbb N}$ be the space of all functions ${\mathbb N}\to {\mathbb Q}$ where ${\mathbb N}=\lbrace 1,2,3,\ldots \rbrace$ is the set of all positive integers.

Let $W$ be the subspace of $W$ defined by

$$
W=\lbrace f\in V \ | \ f(a)+f(b)=f(c)+f(d) \ \textrm{if} \ a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2, \ a,b,c,d \in {\mathbb N}\rbrace
$$

**My question :** What is the dimension of $W$ ?

**What I did :** I have shown that $\dim(W) \leq 6$ ; in fact, any
$f(n)(n\in{\mathbb N})$ is a linear combination of $f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(6)$.
Indeed, the identities $1^2+7^2=5^2+5^2$, $1^2+8^2=4^2+7^2$, $2^2+9^2=6^2+7^2$,
$3^2+11^2=7^2+9^2$, $5^2+10^2=2^2+11^2$, yield succesively that this property is true for $7,8,9,11$, and $10$. Next, it is a simple enough arithmetical lemma that for $n\geq 12$, there are $a,b,c$ with $1\leq a,b,c \lt n$ such that
$n^2+a^2=b^2+c^2$ (this is shown in different ways in different answers of [an older MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718614/functions-f-mathbbz-to-mathbbr-satisfying-x-fy-y-fx-xy) ), so that we are then done.

Numerical experiments suggest that the dimension is exactly $6$.

**UPDATE 10/04/2020 :** The dimension of $W$ is at least four because $W$ contains the constants, the square function, the characteristic function of the numbers divisible by $4$ ($f(n)=1$ if $n$ is divisible by 4, and $f(n)=0$ otherwise), and the characteristic function of the odd numbers.

Here's what the beginning of the sequence corresponding to $f(1)=-1$, $f(k)=0$ for $2\leq k \leq 6$ looks like :

$-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 20, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 37, 40, 41, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 55, 58, 59, 62, 64, 68, 70, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 86, 90, 92, 96, 99, 102, 105, 108, 112, 116$

The sequence seems to be nondecreasing (from the ninth term on)  and nonnegative (except for the first term).

Comment: Find $6$ linearly independent functions in $W$?

Comment: The constant and the last three characteristic functions are not linearly independent, so you can only get $\operatorname{dim}W \ge 4$.

Comment: @Zerox Corrected, thanks

Comment: @Zerox Sure, but that's what we want to prove, not what we have proven

Comment: @EwanDelanoy There's a bunch of functions $f(a)=a^2 (\operatorname{mod}p)$ may satisfy the equation. I verified it when $p=3, 5$.

Comment: @Zerox Indeed. So we have found all the six of them. If you write that as an answer I'll accept it. By the way, $f(a)=a^2(\mod p)$ is a solution for all $p$, not just a "bunch" of primes $p$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Isn't there probability that $f(a)+f(b)=f(c)+f(d)+p$? I don't know much about quadratic residue so I can't ensure all primes satisfy.

Comment: @Zerox No, you're right. You have a map ${\mathbb N} \to \frac{\mathbb Z}{p\mathbb Z}$ that has the property, but, as you said, one might have $f(a)+f(b)=f(c)+f(d)+p$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two missing functions are the characteristic function of the multiples of $3$, and the Legendre symbol $n\mapsto\left(\frac{n}{5}\right)$. To check that these functions satisfy the given property, observe that the function value depends only on the input mod $3$ (resp. mod $5$), so it is enough to check the condition for $1\leq a,b\leq 3$ (resp. $1\leq a,b\leq 5$), a finite computation. Combined with the set of four functions your found, this gives six linearly independent solutions, which must be a basis.

For your example $f(1)=-1$, $f(k)=0$ for $2\leq k\leq 6$, I solved a linear system to find
$$
f(n)=-\frac{1}{8}\chi_{2\mathbb{Z}+1}(n) +\frac{1}{2}\chi_{4\mathbb{Z}}(n)-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{40}n^2-\frac{2}{5}\left(\frac{n}{5}\right).
$$